# PHP regex template condition

Tags: php, regex, template-engine

I'm trying to make a templating engine for my project and I have a problem with parsing condition.

**i want this in template:**

```
=if $var == "ee":
  << $variable >>
=elseif $var == "aaa":
  << $variable >>
=else:
  << $variable >>
=endif
```

**and in processed template must be:**

```
<?php if($var == "ee"){ ?>
   <?= $variable ?>
<?php }elseif($var == "aaa") { ?>
   <?= $variable ?>
<?php }else{ ?>
   <?= $variable ?>
<?php } ?>
```

Can anybody help me with that? I need to parse those conditions only to the classic php conditions. Thanks for early answer.

Comment: Can't you just `str_replace` the `<?=` and `?>`?

Comment: Why do you want to reinvent the wheel? Why not use an established template engine?